# Setting OS User with Oracle Call Interface (OCI)

Tags: oracle, go, oracle-call-interface, oci8

I'm trying to change the OS User that is passed to Oracle during database connection set up in golang oracle [oci-8 driver](https://github.com/mattn/go-oci8). This is in a similar way to setting the `v$session.osuser` in the Java JDBC drivers. I'm trying to modify mattn's go-oci8 oracle driver so I can change the os user value on the fly. I've tried adding `conn.attrs.Set("os_user", "test_os_user")` in the open method.

I've trawled through the [oci docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10779/ociaahan.htm) and I think I might need to set `OCI_ATTR_CLIENT_IDENTIFIER` but I can work out if this is correct or how to do it. Any ideas if it is possible (and how) to change the osuser value using OCI?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that it is not possible to set the OS User with the OCI driver. The [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleConnection.html#CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_VSESSION_OSUSER) for Java highlights that setting the OS User is only possible when the oracle Java Thin driver is used.